# Notification not automatically cancel when addAction

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have tested the new BigTextStyle Notification which display correctly. However when I add action to the notification, it never get cancel and the pull-down notification area is never close when click on the action. What did I do wrong?

```
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
    Notification noti = null;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

    String s = "Name: John \n"
            + "Surname: Doe\n"
            + "Vehicle: Honda Jazz TA-1234\n"
            + "Note: Good drifter";

    Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setContentTitle("New challenger arrived!")
            .setContentText(s)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(b)
            .setTicker("New challenger arrived!")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setNumber(5)
            .addAction(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add,
                    "Accept",
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                            notificationIntent, 0, null))
            .addAction(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete,
                    "Refuse",
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                            notificationIntent, 0, null))
            .addAction(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map,
                    "Map",
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, null));

    noti = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
                        .setBigContentTitle("New challenger arrived!")
                        .bigText(s)
                        .setSummaryText("You will never win against me").build();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    nm.notify(0, noti);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manually cancel the notifications if you take an action. This can be done by calling

```
notifMgr.cancel(0);
```

Clicking the notification itself should dismiss it, but for some reason actions don't seem to. The reason you pass 0 as the argument is becasue that's the ID you gave when you called:

```
notifMgr.notify(0, noti);
```

That's my updated answer, however, I had previously answered this:

It looks like you're trying to launch the same activity (from your PendingIntent) that you currently have displayed (I'm assuming this is a 1-activity app, with MainActivity containing the code above). Create another activity, build your PendingIntent so it launches that activity, then it should do as you wish. Alternatively, run your activity, notification appears, navigate to homescreen, or different app, then act on your Activity, your desired behavior should manifest.